# how to buy bsc tokens with high tax using web3.py

Tags: blockchain, web3.py, python, bsc

heres the function i have to try and buy a token with 15% tax on a bsc

```
    tokenToBuy = web3.to_checksum_address(tokenAddress)
    spend = web3.to_checksum_address("0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c") #wbnb addy
    contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapRouterAddress, abi=pancakeABI)
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress)
    gas_price = get_gas_limit_estimate()


    print(f'attempting to buy {buyBnbAmount} of {tokenToBuy}')

    amount_in = \
    contract.functions.getAmountsIn(web3.to_wei(float(buyBnbAmount), 'ether'), [spend, tokenToBuy]).call()[-1]
    slippage = 0.3
    min_tokens = int(amount_in * (1 - slippage))

    pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        min_tokens,  # The minimum amount of tokens to receive
        [spend, tokenToBuy],
        walletAddress,
        (int(time.time()) + transactionRevertTime)  # deadline
    ).build_transaction({
        'from': walletAddress,
        'value': web3.to_wei(float(buyBnbAmount), 'ether'),
        'gas': gasAmount,
        'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gas_price, 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })

    try:
        signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key)
        tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f" Transaction failed. {e}")
        return

    txHash = str(web3.to_hex(tx_token))

    checkTransactionURL = "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=transaction&action=gettxreceiptstatus&txhash=" + txHash + "&apikey=" + bscScanAPIKey
    checkTransaction = requests.get(url=checkTransactionURL)
    tx = checkTransaction.json()['status']
    if (tx == "1"):
        print(" Successfully bought " + tokenAddress + " for " + str(
            buyBnbAmount) + " BNB - TX ID: ", txHash)
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        print(" Transaction failed: likely not enough gas.")
```

this is initially a successful request and returns "1", but 10 seconds later when i check the txhash it says

> *Fail with error 'Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED'
> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
> [CANCELLED]*

The code works great for no tax and even sub 5% tax bsc coins but continues to give problems for any with higher taxes